# AutoscalerDatapoints table limit with Wasabi

Tags: azure, autoscaling, wasabi

I am using WASABI in my Azure project. My autoscaler is set correctly and works fine. The problem I have is that after some days, the autoscaler is stuck on old values. For instance, it would say that the number of items in my watched queue is 3, when the queue is empty.

I realized that by deleting the **AutoscalerDatapoints** table (using [Neudesic Azure Storage Explorer](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/)) and recreating it, the autoscaler starts working again. This might just be a working solution to another problem...

So, my question is : Is there a limit to the number of entries an Azure Table can keep ? If so, how can I solve this problem in an automated way ?

Thank you for your help and don't hesitate if you need more info.

Comment: There is no limit on the number of data points, only the one set by the storage account (which is 100TB I believe, so can be ignored). Can you share how you defined the operand that monitors the queue?